# Looking for a PC video card for multiple video visualization

Tags: video, graphics-card, video-streaming

We have developed a blast furnace tuyere monitoring system using a C# WinForms application that displays up to **45 MJPEG video streams**. Thoses streams appears in a **mosaic view of thumbnails** on a 1920x1020 Full HD screen.

The user is able to choose the amount of videos he wants to see on the same screen. Depending on the screen size and the client PC performances, the **video resolution** can be tuned to a fixed set from **320x240** to **800x600**.

We are using as many Axis Ip cameras as needed for the video acquisition, and we use the Axis Media Control to display the stream in our application.

The system has been installed at several customer sites and is able to display 35 videos at 320x240 resolution (24fps) smoothly enough, even with a basic video card.

Some of our customers wants to run the application using the 800x600 thumbnails resolution, because their 42 inch screen is big and makes thumbnails look ugly in 320x240.

Unfortunately, our application **suffers from video freezing and stuttering with 35 videos at 800x600**.

That's why we would like to buy some video card that would display the more video possible using the best resolution we can.

Unfortunately, they are so many models and brands available that I struggle to compare them each other. So, based on my constraints, **which technical criteria should I focus on to decide which video card I need ?**

Comment: To whomever did/may vote to close this as a Hardware Recommendation request, please consider it's actually written the way we want/accept it: `Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs` -- ie: "So, based on my constraints, which technical criteria should I focus on to decide which video card I need?"

Comment: Since you don't mention it, I'll ask the obvious - is your application running on a gigabit network? Depending on the video codec used by the cameras, a 100 megabit network may be too slow to handle the video.

Comment: You're right sorry I forgot to mention this. Yes, client PC are running on a gigabit network, this is part of our requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found everything explained in details in [this very well written white book](http://www.cohuhd.com/Portals/0/Files/white_papers/CohuHDVideoRenderingBasicsWhitePaper.pdf). Basically, the reference used in the benchmarks represents the overall performances of a graphic card, not only the 3D.

The issue is to find a balance between the CPU, the network bandwidth and the video card capabilities.

We added some options to tweak the frame rate, the resolution and the MJPEG compression depending on the situation, and it helped a lot, even with a basic video card. A 350$ GeForce allowed us to push things a bit further for high-demanding customers.

So I can consider this case as closed.